# How to solve this issue: No matching records found (ODBC -2028) when I try to make a post?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sapui5, service-layer

I am trying to add a timesheet in SAP B1 via lambda/AWS.
My code already worked before but, now, it returns me this error - No matching records found (ODBC -2028).

Can you please help me.

This is my code for post:

```
addNewAppointment: function(sId, sTitle, sDescription, sDate, sSTime, sETime,sType){    
            var url = "/destinations/IBC/add";
            var query = "ProjectManagementTimeSheet";
            var json =  {   
                            "servicoSL": query, 
                            "DateFrom": sDate.value, 
                            "PM_TimeSheetLineDataCollection": [ 
                                {                               
                                    "ActivityType": sType.value, 
                                    "Date": sDate.value,
                                    "EndTime": sETime.value,
                                    "StartTime": sSTime.value
                                }
                            ],
                            "UserID": sId.value
                        };
            $.ajax({
                "url": url,
                "method": "POST",
                "timeout": 0,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
            
                "data": JSON.stringify(json),
                
                success: function (data) {
                    
        
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    
                }
            }); 
        },
```

This is the code for thebutton:

```
handleDialogOkButton: function (){
            var oId = Fragment.byId("dialogFrag", "userId").getValue(),
                oTitle = Fragment.byId("dialogFrag", "appTitle").getValue(),
                oDescription = Fragment.byId("dialogFrag", "moreInfo").getValue(),
                oSDate = Fragment.byId("dialogFrag", "sDTDate").getDateValue(),
                _sDate = new Date(oSDate),
                oEDate = Fragment.byId("dialogFrag", "eDTDate").getDateValue(),
                _eDate = new Date(oEDate),
                oType = Fragment.byId("dialogFrag", "type").getValue();

                
            if (oSDate !== "Error"
                && oEDate !== "Error") {
                var sId = oId,
                    sType = oType.slice(0,2),
                    sTitle = oTitle,
                    sDescription = oDescription,                
                    Month = _sDate.getMonth(),
                    sMonth = Month + 1,
                    sSDate = _sDate.getFullYear() + "-" + sMonth + "-" + _sDate.getDate(),
                    sSTime = _sDate.getHours() + ":" + _sDate.getMinutes(),
                    sETime = _eDate.getHours() + ":" + _eDate.getMinutes();
                
                this.addNewAppointment(sId, sTitle, sDescription, sSDate, sSTime, sETime,sType);
                this._oNewAppointmentDialog.close();
            } else {
                this.getTimeSheet();
            }
        },
```

This is the error that I have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODHrx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check also with this note

1711242 - Error message pops up when adding landed costs via copying from landed costs created before 8.81 PL10

Symptom

You work on a company database of China localization. You try to add the landed costs via copying from landed costs created before 8.81 PL10. You find the "Supplementary Code" field is grey and blank. When clicking on "Add", error message pops up as "No matching records found 'Delivery Types' (OSHP) (ODBC -2028) [Message 131-183]".

Cause

Application Error

Solution

SAP intends to provide a patch or patches in order to solve the problem described.
The section Reference to Related Notes below will list the specific patches once they become available.
The corresponding Info file of the patches in SAP Service Marketplace will also show the SAP Note number.
Be aware that these references can only be set at patch release date.
SAP will deliver patches only for selected releases at its own discretion, based on the business impact and the complexity of the implementation.

Other terms

AP, AR, recalculate, custom, GRPO

Header Data

Released On 26.04.2012 04:16:20 Release Status Released for Customer Component SBO-PUR-LAN Landed Costs Other Components

SBO-ADM-INI-DON Document Numbering
Priority Correction with high priority Category Program error

References

This document is referenced by:

SAP Business One Notes (1)
1715422 Overview Note for SAP Business One 8.82 PL07

Validity

Software Component

Version

SAP BUSINESS ONE

8.82

Hope Helpful

Regards

Kennedy

detail:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/9972511/no-matching-records-found.html

Comment: Hi, 
thank you for your answer.
Just another situation - I'm not working on a company database of China localization.
I'm in Portugal and the company database is in Portugal also. I already checked.
It is possible happening the same?